# How can I put objects from a Get- command in a list/array?

Tags: powershell

I just started a new internship and right now I'm working with Powershell to get the hang of it.
My exercise right now is to write a script that will select 50 random computers from the DNS record and delete the name and the associated IP or the record.

My issue is that I don't know how to add the list of DNS records to an array list where I can delete them by the index value.  I've tried various methods but with no avail.

This is what I have so far:

```
    #this is getting all the objects that i need from the DNS record, its a test environment
$ListDNS = Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName "win-309382aqq99" -ZoneName 'www.abc.com' -RRType A | Where-Object {$_.HostName -like "ABC-PC-*"} | FT Hostname

$testArray = @()
Function addToArray($ListDNS) 
{
$testArray += $ListaDNS
}



$counter_elements = 0

Foreach( $var in $ListDNS) {

$counter_elements++
}

$counter_delete = 0
while($counter_delete -ne 50) {

$random_number = get-random -Maximum $counter_elements -Minimum 0
$testArray.RemoveAt($random_number)
$counter_elements--
$counter_delete++

}
```

I'm pretty sure the first array is not working. I'm aware this is probably too over-engineered and powershell has better commands I could use but I'm working with what I can right now.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap the `Get-DnsServerResourceRecord ...` pipeline in the **array subexpression operator** - `@()` - the result will always be an array type:

```
$records = @(Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName "win-309382aqq99" -ZoneName 'www.abc.com' -RRType A | Where-Object {$_.HostName -like "ABC-PC-*"})

# We can count the records
$records.Count

# We can address the individual records by index
$records[0]
```

---

To pick 50 records at random, simply pipe the whole array to `Get-Random -Count 50`:

```
$recordsToDelete = $records |Get-Random -Count 50

foreach($item in $recordsToDelete){
  # perform deletion here
}
```